# Request/Reply and Retry Policy for Kafka Listeners

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-retry

I’m currently implementing an error handling mechanism for Kafka Listeners. This is what I would like to achieve: when an exception occurs within a Kafka Listener, I want to retry processing my record 10 times and if it still fails, send it to a dead letter queue and inform the sender in case of a request/reply scenario (returning a specific RecordFailure object for example).
I first defined an ErrorHandler bean which worked fine but didn’t offer the possibility to return a value in case of failure. Then I moved to defining a KafkaListenerErrorHandler bean and specifying it as a parameter of my Kafka Listener. It allowed me to return a specific value but I lost the retry and dead letter queue forwarding policy defined by the ErrorHandler. Eventually, I went with configuring my container factory with a RetryTemplate and RecoveryCallback. I thought it would work as expected but when using a ReplyingKafkaTemplate to send my message, I always end up receiving a timeout exception and realise that, since I defined a RetryTemplate, the onMessage() method from the RetryingMessageListenerAdapter was called instead of the ReplyingKafkaTemplate one. I’m now questioning the scenario itself: does it make sense to combine both a RetryTemplate, a RecoveryCallback and a ReplyingKafkaTemplate to enable request/reply with retry policies using a Kafka Listener? If so, what am I missing here?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Using a retry template at the listener level is mostly redundant now that the error handlers support backoff and retry.

One way to solve your particular problem would be to enable `deliveryAttemptHeader`s.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#delivery-header

Then, in your listener error handler, check the header and when the specific number of attempts is reached, publish the message to a dead letter topic and return the error result. Before the count is reached re-throw the exception so that the `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` will redeliver the record.

Just make sure that the STCEH has enough retries so it always retries, enabling the listener error handler to do its work.

**EDIT**

Here's an example, showing how to use the DLPR from a listener error handler, by adding the raw `ConsumerRecord` in a header...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So66982480Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So66982480Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> rkt(ProducerFactory<String, String> pf,
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory,
            KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {

        factory.getContainerProperties().setDeliveryAttemptHeader(true);
        factory.setReplyTemplate(template);
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container = factory.createContainer("so66982480-replies");
        container.getContainerProperties().setGroupId("so66982480-replies");
        return new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(pf, container);
    }

    @Bean
    RecordMessageConverter converter() {
        MessagingMessageConverter converter = new MessagingMessageConverter() {

            @Override
            public Message<?> toMessage(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record, Acknowledgment acknowledgment,
                    Consumer<?, ?> consumer, Type type) {

                Message<?> message = super.toMessage(record, acknowledgment, consumer, type);
                return MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message)
                        .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.RAW_DATA, record)
                        .build();
            }

        };
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    KafkaTemplate<String, String> template(ProducerFactory<String, String> pf) {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(pf);
    }

    @Bean
    NewTopic topic1() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so66982480").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    NewTopic topic2() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so66982480-replies").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    NewTopic topic3() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so66982480.DLT").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    KafkaListenerErrorHandler eh(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer recoverer) {
        return (msg, ex) -> {
            if (msg.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.DELIVERY_ATTEMPT, Integer.class) > 9) {
                recoverer.accept(msg.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.RAW_DATA, ConsumerRecord.class), ex);
                return "FAILED";
            }
            throw ex;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer recoverer(KafkaOperations<String, String> template) {
        return new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so66982480", topics = "so66982480", errorHandler = "eh")
    @SendTo
    public String listen(String in) {
        throw new RuntimeException("test");
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so66982480.DLT", topics = "so66982480.DLT")
    public void dlt(String in) {
        System.out.println("From DLT:" + in);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            RequestReplyFuture<String, String, String> future =
                    template.sendAndReceive(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("so66982480", 0, null, "test"),
                            Duration.ofSeconds(30));
            System.out.println(future.getSendFuture().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).getRecordMetadata());
            System.out.println(future.get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).value());
        };
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
```

```
From DLT:test
FAILED
```

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the situation. I tried your solution setting the DeliveryAttemptHeaders in the container and using the KafkaListenerErrorHandler in combination with a custom STCEH to set my retry policy, it solved the issue! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Gary, your solution still works perfectly fine! I progressed my solution now and am using a @Transactional annotated Kafka Listener. Is the solution you proposed still working in this context ? I have the impression that the DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor takes over and always retries even if I return a value in my KafkaListenerErrorHandler.

Comment: I'd need more details to understand what's going on; I suggest you ask a new question showing relevant code and configuration  (and logs).

Comment: Ofc, here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68215296/error-handling-in-transactional-kafka-listeners