# Error Handling in Transactional Kafka Listeners

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, transactions, spring-kafka

This question follows my post on [Request/Reply and Retry Policy for Kafka Listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66982480/request-reply-and-retry-policy-for-kafka-listeners) but in the context of Transactional Kafka Listeners (the current implementation is therefore similar to the proposed solution).
Basically, the idea is to be able to support a complete error management which is, based on the type of exception, either retry X times the record or send it to a dead letter topic for exception raised inside a Kafka Listener tagged with @Transactional.
When I specify the *errorHandler* parameter to my @KafkaListener, I can see that it goes through my logic for the first time but then, after sending to the dead letter topic (and returning my custom response in case of @SendTo), it rolls back the transaction and retries to process my record as defined by the BackOff period of the DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor.
Is there anyway to prevent these retries in the case the exception has been properly handled and then just carry on with the next transaction ?

Here are my various handlers defined as suggested by the solution in the above link:

```
    @Bean
    public ErrorHandler errorHandler(MyDeadLetterQueueHandler deadLetterQueueHandler) {
        //set with retry policy higher than KafkaListenerErrorHandler
        return new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler((data, thrownException) -> {
                deadLetterQueueHandler.send(data, thrownException);
        }, new FixedBackOff(15000, 20));
    }

    @Bean
    public AfterRollbackProcessor<?, ?> afterRollbackProcessor(MyDeadLetterQueueHandler deadLetterQueueHandler) {
        //set with retry policy higher than KafkaListenerErrorHandler
        final var afterRollbackProcessor = new DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor<Object, Object>(((data, thrownException) -> {
                deadLetterQueueHandler.send(data, thrownException);
        }, new FixedBackOff(15000, 20));
        afterRollbackProcessor.setCommitRecovered(true);
        return afterRollbackProcessor;
    }

    
    @Primary
    KafkaListenerErrorHandler kafkaListenerErrorHandler(MyDeadLetterQueueHandler deadLetterQueueHandler,
                                                        MyExceptionHandler exceptionHandler) {
        return (message, exception) -> {
            final var cause = (Exception) exception.getCause();
            final var consumerRecord = message.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.RAW_DATA, ConsumerRecord.class);
            if (shouldGoToDLT(cause)) {
                sendToDeadLetterTopic(deadLetterQueueHandler, consumerRecord, cause);
                return new CustomResponse(cause.getMessage());
                // should end transaction rollback and go to next transaction
            } else {
                // retry 10 times before killing the app
                var deliveryAttempt = message.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.DELIVERY_ATTEMPT, Integer.class);
                if (deliveryAttempt > 10) {
                    exceptionHandler.handle(cause);
                }
            }
            throw exception;
        };
    }
```

and the logs that I get from my test using EmbeddedKafkaBroker and throwing an exception in a @Transactional Kafka Listener:

```
2021-07-01 17:12:34.791  INFO [,0beec62e5e3dbb97,0beec62e5e3dbb97] 19210 --- [ntainer#1-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-consumer-group.rollback-db-employee-topic.0, transactionalId=consumer-group.rollback-db-employee-topic.0] Aborting incomplete transaction
2021-07-01 17:12:34.812 ERROR [,0beec62e5e3dbb97,0beec62e5e3dbb97] 19210 --- [ntainer#1-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Transaction rolled back

org.springframework.transaction.HeuristicCompletionException: Heuristic completion: outcome state is rolled back; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
    at org.springframework.data.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager.commit(ChainedTransactionManager.java:195)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeInTransaction(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2072)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListenerInTx(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2041)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2017)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1702)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1272)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1161)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:752)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.data.transaction.MultiTransactionStatus.commit(MultiTransactionStatus.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager.commit(ChainedTransactionManager.java:168)
    ... 11 common frames omitted

2021-07-01 17:12:34.918  INFO [,0beec62e5e3dbb97,0beec62e5e3dbb97] 19210 --- [ntainer#1-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-group-3, groupId=consumer-group] Seeking to offset 0 for partition rollback-db-employee-topic-0
2021-07-01 17:12:34.929  INFO [,0beec62e5e3dbb97,2d5e98ce0b91d04a] 19210 --- [ntainer#1-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-consumer-group.rollback-db-employee-topic.0, transactionalId=consumer-group.rollback-db-employee-topic.0] Aborting incomplete transaction
2021-07-01 17:12:34.931 ERROR [,0beec62e5e3dbb97,2d5e98ce0b91d04a] 19210 --- [ntainer#1-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Transaction rolled back

org.springframework.transaction.HeuristicCompletionException: Heuristic completion: outcome state is rolled back; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
    at org.springframework.data.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager.commit(ChainedTransactionManager.java:195)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeInTransaction(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2072)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListenerInTx(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2041)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2017)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1702)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1272)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1161)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:752)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.data.transaction.MultiTransactionStatus.commit(MultiTransactionStatus.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager.commit(ChainedTransactionManager.java:168)
    ... 11 common frames omitted

2021-07-01 17:12:35.034  INFO [,0beec62e5e3dbb97,2d5e98ce0b91d04a] 19210 --- [ntainer#1-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-group-3, groupId=consumer-group] Seeking to offset 0 for partition rollback-db-employee-topic-0
2021-07-01 17:12:35.445  INFO [,0beec62e5e3dbb97,4ef5c58e90699a09] 19210 --- [ntainer#1-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-consumer-group.rollback-db-employee-topic.0, transactionalId=consumer-group.rollback-db-employee-topic.0] Aborting incomplete transaction
2021-07-01 17:12:35.448 ERROR [,0beec62e5e3dbb97,4ef5c58e90699a09] 19210 --- [ntainer#1-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Transaction rolled back

org.springframework.transaction.HeuristicCompletionException: Heuristic completion: outcome state is rolled back; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
    at org.springframework.data.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager.commit(ChainedTransactionManager.java:195)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeInTransaction(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2072)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListenerInTx(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2041)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2017)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1702)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1272)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1161)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:752)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.data.transaction.MultiTransactionStatus.commit(MultiTransactionStatus.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager.commit(ChainedTransactionManager.java:168)
    ... 11 common frames omitted

…
```

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**: Here's my listener:

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = "user-topic", groupId = "consumer-group-1", errorHandler ="errorHandler")
    @Transactional
    public void onReceive(User command) {
        // update database
        userRepository.save(command);

        switch (command.getName()) {
            case "GOTODLT":
                var volunteerArithmeticException = 7 / 0;
                break;
            case "SHOULDRETRY":
                throw new IllegalStateException("Should be retried 10 times");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear why you are using `@Transactional` since you are using a `ChainedKafkaTransactionManager` (which is deprecated by the way; see the parent class javadocs). It is ok to use it, as long as you are aware of the limitations.

The transactions have already been started by the transaction managers, so the annotation is not needed.

Since your listener method is wrapped in a transaction interceptor, the transaction is rolled back before your listener error handler is invoked.

Hence the `Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only` message.

Remove the annotation and it should work as you expect.

You should not configure both a STCEH and ARP. The former runs inside the transaction, the latter after a rollback.